# Python:- Convert a string into list

Tags: python, regex, string, list, types

I have a string like `groups(1,12,23,12)` and I want to convert it into a list like `[1,12, 23, 12]`.

I tried this code, but output is not as excepted.

```
str = 'groups(1,12,23,12)'
lst = [x for x in str]
```

Please let me know...!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Use regular expression to find numbers from the input string.
2. Use map method to convert string to integer.

e.g.

```
>>> import re
>>> a = 'groups(1,12,23,12)'
>>> re.findall("\d+", a)
['1', '12', '23', '12']
>>> map(int, re.findall("\d+", a))
[1, 12, 23, 12]
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use `re.findall` method.

And don't use `str` as variable name.

```
>>> import re
>>> s = 'groups(1,12,23,12)'
>>> re.findall(r'\d+', string)
['1', '12', '23', '12']
>>> [int(i) for i in re.findall(r'\d+', s)]
[1, 12, 23, 12]
```

Without regex,

```
>>> s = 'groups(1,12,23,12)'
>>> [int(i) for i in s.split('(')[1].split(')')[0].split(',')]
[1, 12, 23, 12]
```

Comment: Using string as variable name is also a bad idea :-)

Comment: there is an in-built python module name string. So definitely a bad idea. Try `import string`

Answer (score 3):

For an approach without regex

```
>>> a = "groups(1,12,23,12)"
>>> a= a.replace('groups','')
>>> import ast
>>> list(ast.literal_eval(a))
[1, 12, 23, 12]
```

Ref:

- [The `ast` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval)
- [`str.replace` method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace)

Comment: the advantage to this over regex is that it will work with any type of number  eg. `1e4`, `1.99`, `0x9` etc.  and it will even work for any other type string, dict, etc I think this is the best approach, the general rule is to always avoid regex where possible as well

Answer (score 0):

```
string = "groups(1,12,23,12)".replace('groups(','').replace(')','')
outputList = [int(x) for x in string.split(',')]
```